# utilizando classe java de outro diretório

Tags: java

Pois bem amigos, eu estava utilizando duas classes:

`Funcionario.java` (classe 1, do diretório `/home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio3`) e `UtilizandoFuncionario.java` (classe 2, do diretório `/home/lcs/Documentos/java`).

Até aí tudo bem, eu utilizava na classe 2 o comando `import exercicio3.Funcionario;` e funcionava direitinho, porém quando eu coloquei a classe 2 no diretório `/home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio4` o comando parou de funcionar e começou a dar erro no terminal.

Gostaria de saber como utilizar a classe Funcionario na classe UtilizandoFuncionario no novo diretório, no caso `/home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio4`?

```
package exercicio3; 

public class Funcionario { 
  private int matricula; 
  private double salario; 
  //RESTO DO CÓDIGO ... 
} 



package java; 
import exercicio3.Funcionario; 
public class UtilizandoFuncionario { 
  public static void main(String ... args){ 
    //RESTO DO CÓDIGO ... 
  } 
}
```

Usei para compilar:

```
Documentos/java/exercicio4$ javac UtilizndoFuncionario.java
```

Comment: manda a estrutura de diretórios, o código da importação e a sua chamada no console.

Comment: Você alterou o seu import? Tem que alterar ele tb, se alterou o endereço dos seus arquivos...

Comment: Desculpe a demora...

O diretório da classe Funcionario.java é: /home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio3
   package exercicio3;
   public class Funcionario{
       private int matricula;
       private double salario;
       //RESTO DO CÓDIGO
       ...
    }


Enquanto a classe UtilizandoFuncionario.java estava em: /home/lcs/Documentos/java
    package java;
    import exercicio3.Funcionario;
    public class UtilizandoFuncionario{
        public static void main(String ... args){
            //RESTO DO CÓDIGO
            ...
        }
    }

Comment: No terminal eu utilizava o seguinte comando, com o terminal dentro do diretório: lcs@LcsMarlon:~/Documentos/java$ javac UtilizandoFuncionario.java
Compilava tudo direitinho, porém quando eu mudei o arquivo UtilizandoFuncionario.java para o outro diretório: /home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio4 
Começou a dar erro quando eu digitava no terminal, no diretório novo é claro: 
lcs@LcsMarlon:~/Documentos/java/exercicio4$ javac UtilizndoFuncionario.java
Apresentava o erro:
UtilizandoFuncionario.java:1: error: package exercicio3 does not exist
import exercicio3.Funcionario;
1 error
    @ulima69

Comment: Como eu alteraria o meu import @DiegoSantos??? Eu tentei, mas não consigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo terminal, no diretório em que se encontrava o arquivo `Funcionario.java` eu dei o seguinte comando:

```
$javac -cp . Funcionario.java -d /home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio4/
```

O comando acima faz com que seja criada automaticamente uma pasta (com o nome do “package” da classe *Java*, no caso foi criada umas pasta com nome *exercicio3*), na pasta *exercicio4*, a qual se encontra o arquivo `UtilizandoFuncionario.java`.

> Nota: o `-d` faz com que o *.class* seja criado no diretório destinado, nesse caso foi o */home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio4/*

Bastou eu importar na classe UtilizandoFuncionario a classe Funcionario com o import, assim ficou:

```
import exercicio3.Funcionario;
//Ou caso tenha mais de uma classe
//import exercicio3.*;

public class UtilizandoFuncionario{
    public static void main(String ... args){
       //Resto do código
    }
}
```

No terminal, bastou eu ir no diretório do arquivo *UtilizandoFuncionario.java* e colocar o comando:

```
$javac UtilizandoFuncionario.java
```

Funcionou tudo direto quando eu testei o programa com o comando:

```
$java UtilizandoFuncionario
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você tenta compilar, o erro surge porque a classe `Funcionario.java` ainda não foi compilada, ou se já foi ainda não está na mesma pasta ou no *classpath* para compilação da classe `UtilizandoFuncionario.java`, logo o compilador não encontra a classe `Funcionario.class`.

Qual o procedimento?

1. Compilar a classe *Funcionario.java* e colocando o *.class* na mesma pasta:

   `$javac -cp . /home/lcs/Documentos/java/exercicio3/Funcionario.java`
2. Compilar a classe principal

   `$javac -cp . UtilizandoFuncionario.java`
3. Rodar a classe principal

   `$java -cp . UtilizandoFuncionario`

A partir do passo 2, o compilador já vai verificar que o arquivo `Funcionario.class` vai estar na pasta e então conseguirá compilar.

Por existirem essas dificuldades de compilação é que usa-se em Java ferramentas de compilação como o *ant* ou *maven*.

No seu caso que está começando, aconselho o bom e velho [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) e uma [apostila da Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/) excelente.